# Транспилировать ES6 код, используя babel и Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babel

Есть собственный модуль с нетранспилированным кодом, который лежит в node_modules. В конфиге webpack прописано следующее:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: ['babel'],
    exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

Я бы хотел исключить транспилирование всего в node_modules, кроме моего модуля. Для этого я написал следующее:

```
exclude: /node_modules(?!\/my_module)/
```

Но нужного результата не получил. При запуске приложения, выскакивает ошибка

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import(…)

Ругается на index.js, в котором подключаются через import необходимые компоненты.

Я попробовал вынести свой модуль из папки node_modules и прописать прямой путь к нему в приложении.

Вместо `import { someComponent } from 'my_module'` я написал следующее `import { someComponent } from '../my_module'`. Естественно, 'my_module' вынес из node_modules в нужную директорию.

По идее, сейчас ограничение на транспиляцию, которое написано в webpack не должно распространяться на мой модуль. Но, почему-то, ошибка не пропадает. По-прежнему код не транспилируется и компилятор ругается на неизвестный ему import. Что делать?

Comment: В общем, нужно больше информации. Могут помочь: package.json, полный конфиг, транспилятся ли файлы без es6-импортов

Comment: Случаем это все не на винде делаете?

Comment: @ruslik на винде

Comment: @ruslik, а причем тут винда-не винда? у меня  с виндой прекрасно работает, и не у одного меня.

Comment: Просто у меня выскакивала аналогичная проблема  Unexpected token import - оказалось что пути неправильно прописаны из за обратного слэша, который в винде \, а в линукс - /

Comment: Поэтому в регулярках нужно писать не `\/`, а `[\\\/]`